# Python - pyodbc, adding unique values to a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

As the title suggests I'm trying to parse data and insert into a postgresql database.

The following 2 functions are what I'm using to try to accomplish this task. As you can see the first function takes the input and converts it to a list of lists.

The for loop iterates through each of the lists and assigns them to an object.
You can see "insertToDatabase()" is called from within the for loop and passes down the objects as strings.

Connection to database is made, and I first run a query to return all of the post_id's from the database, and store into a list. then I try to do "if id not in results", proceed with insert.

However this does not work, my entries get added every time the program runs, making multiple entries of the same. I tried something similar trying to fetch just the last posted entry, ordered by timestamp descending, and doing "if id != last_posted", but that did not work either.

There's got to be a better way to do this. What am I doing wrong here? If the 'id' of a item (ex. '7229511362') already exists in the db, I want to skip re-inserting it into the db and proceed through to loop to check all of the results.

Code:

```
def initialParse(results):
    rList = [list(r.values()) for r in results]

    print(rList)

    for l in rList:
        r_id = str(l[0])
        r_name = str(l[2])
        r_url = str(l[3])
        r_datetime = str(l[4])
        r_updated = str(l[5])
        r_price = str(l[6])
        r_where = str(l[7])

        insertToDatabase(r_id, r_name, r_url, r_datetime, r_updated, r_price, r_where)

def insertToDatabase(id, name, url, date, updated, price, where):
    global last_insert

    cnxn = connectDb()
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select post_id from listings order by tstmp desc')
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    print(results)

    try:
        if id not in results:
            Logger.writeAndPrintLine('Adding ' + id + ' to database...', 0)
            cursor.execute("insert into listings (post_id, timestamp, url, subject, price, location, tstmp) values ("+id+", '"+date+"', '"+url+"', '"+name+"', '"+price+"', '"+where+"', (current_timestamp));")
            print('inserted')
            cursor.commit()
            time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

    cursor.close()
    disconnectDb(cnxn)
```

example of input data after being converted to list of lists:

```
[['7230609794', None, '2004 Nissan Sentra sedan automatic runs excellent', 'https://monterey.craigslist.org/cto/d/salinas-2004-nissan-sentra-sedan/7230609794.html', '2020-11-13 17:35', '2020-11-13 17:35', '$1,850', 'Salinas', True, None, False], ['7230559009', None, '2006 mini cooper', 'https://monterey.craigslist.org/cto/d/king-city-2006-mini-cooper/7230559009.html', '2020-11-13 15:38', '2020-11-13 15:38', '$3,000', 'King city', True, None, False]]
```

Example of what cursor.fetchall() returns:

```
[('7229511362', ), ('7229470879', ), ('7229511362', ), ('7229697890', ), ('7229839309', ), ('7229957054', ), ('7230191646', ), ('7230491972', ), ('7230558061', ), ('7230559009', ), ('7230609794', ), ('7229470879', ), ('7229511362', ), ('7229697890', ), ('7229839309', ), ('7229957054', ), ('7230191646', ), ('7230491972', ), ('7230558061', ), ('7230559009', ), ('7230609794', ), ('7229470879', ), ('7229511362', ), ('7229697890', ), ('7229839309', ), ('7229957054', ), ('7230191646', ), ('7230491972', ), ('7230558061', ), ('7230559009', ), ('7230609794', ), ('7229470879', ), ('7229697890', ), ('7229839309', ), ('7229957054', ), ('7230191646', ), ('7230491972', ), ('7230558061', ), ('7230559009', ), ('7230609794', ), ('7229470879', ), ('7229697890', ), ('7229839309', ), ('7229957054', ), ('7230191646', ), ('7230491972', ), ('7230558061', ), ('7230559009', ), ('7230609794', )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.fetchall()` returns a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects. If you want to use `in` to test whether a particular id value has been returned then you first need to convert that list of `Row` objects into a list of scalar values:

```py
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
rows = crsr.execute("""\
SELECT 'foo' AS col1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar' AS col1
""").fetchall()
print(rows)  # [('foo', ), ('bar', )]
print("foo" in rows)  # False
ids = [row[0] for row in rows]
print(ids)  # ['foo', 'bar']
print("foo" in ids)  # True
```